# Hydrogen energy state transition times and probabilites

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, photons, electrons, hydrogen

1. How correlated is the energy absorbed to the later energy emitted, and hence to the transition type?
2. What is the scale of time it takes to make a downward transition in energy level?
3. In a very cold isolated "cell", lets say an electron is at level 5. What is the probability distribution of going to 4,3,2,1. and also for the times?